# Microsoft PowerPoint ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.view.player() for media in master view

Tags: vba, powerpoint

in Visual Basic for Powerpoint there is a method [ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.view.player](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowview.player)() which gives a set of controls and elapsed time for media embedded in a slide. this is relatively straightforward for videos placed directly in a slide, but I have a presentation that has a video in the slide master, and would like to know if it is posible to use `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.view.player(someId)`, where `someId` refers to the id of a slide in the master for the current slide

When I try this I get an error ('invalid shape id'), presumably because there is an unrelated set of ids used in the master vs the slide itself

alternatively is there another way to get to the runtime player objects and work backwards to find the media object it refers to in the slides array or master.slides array?

Comment: SlideShowWindow deals only with the slides in the show, there is no connection with the layout that is the parent to the slide. A layout is not a slide, it is a template for a slide. So there is no slide id to be found for a layout. In any case, adding a video to a master is a poor practice, since it gives the presentation an irreducibly large file size.

Comment: You clearly don't understand how PowerPoint stores embedded files..  you can have the same video on every slide, it gets stored once and referenced each time, assuming you define it in the master layout . Try it. Rename the PPTX to .zip and look in ppt/media

Comment: I guess I've been schooled. https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/09/ooxml-hacking-buy-the-book/ So what's the answer to your question then?